# How to access different MySQL databases in a same instance in Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, schema, amazon-rds

In my Amazon RDS Dashboard, the configuration details of my DB instance (running MySQL) mentions that my DB name is *ebdb*, which is the default one, I haven't changed it. It's the same screen as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443481/aws-rds-instance-change-db-name), instead that I don't want to change the instance name.

I've managed to connect to this DB using MySQL Workbench and I've imported a schema *carpool* which now lies alongside the existing *ebdb* one:

[image: MySQL Workbench Navigator]

In the config of my app I've specified this DB url: *jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:3306/carpool*, DB_HOST being the endpoint specified in the RDS Dashboard.

If my app tries to access the DB it throws an error because it can't find the table. I assume that's because it looks in the wrong database.

In the RDS Dashboard, placing the cursor on the label *DB Name* gives some info, including *An Amazon DB instance can host multiple databases*. Then why is the name of the database hard-coded *ebdb* ?

How can I access another database in my RDS instance ?

Comment: are You use same user for Workbench and for application?

Comment: Yes the user is the right one. If it wasn't I assume that the error message would rather be something like 'access to DB refused'.

Comment: Is the user you are using allowed to see only the one database?  What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: It's a Hibernate error: *HHH000262: Table not found*. You mean that a user may have acces to one database and not another on the same instance? How can I see what database the user has access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was living in a lie.

The simple reason why I couldn't access my table on RDS was because RDS runs on Linux and MySQL table names are case-sensitive on Linux, while my local DB runs on Windows where MySQL table names are not case-sensitive.

About multiple databases in a single RDS instance: RDS does accept multiple databases. It's just that, for an unknown reason, only the *initial* database of the instance is always displayed in the dashboard. This still doesn't make sense to me because this database has nothing more than other ones, apart being the *first* one.